# Failed Updating using "dnf update" Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, dnf

Hi the other day I tried to update my packages, but I ran into some issues:
using "dnf update" I get following Error:
Error:
Problem: conflicting requests
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
(after using the recommendet flag I just get the same error)
this seems to be a problem many people struggle with, but none of the solutions I found worked for me.

I also tried following command: "dnf install kernel-core"

Package kernel-core-6.2.9-300.fc38.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-core-6.5.9-200.fc38.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-core-6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64 is already installed.
Package kernel-core-6.5.11-300.fc39.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.

Problem 1: package kernel-modules-extra-6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64 from @System requires kernel-uname-r = 6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed

- conflicting requests
  Problem 2: package kernel-6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64 from @System requires kernel-core-uname-r = 6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
  Problem 3: package kernel-modules-6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64 from @System requires kernel-modules-core-uname-r = 6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
  Nothing to do.
  Complete!

I'm quite stuck at the moment, I would greatly appreciate if someone would help me :)

Comment: You have both Fedora 38 and 39 kernel packages installed `kernel-6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64` and `kernel-core-6.5.11-300.fc39.x86_64`.  The conflicts look to be from the Fedora 38 kernels.  If you are running on the Fedora 39 kernel (6.5.11, check with `uname -r`), check to make sure your upgrade process worked properly to completion, then remove the Fedora 38 kernels (and possibly any leftover `f38` packages) to see if that fixes your issues.

Comment: Hi thanks for your helpful reply :) I am currently running following version of the kernel 6.2.9-300.fc38.x86_64
How do I ensure that the new kernel is properly implementet?

Comment: That is another Fedora 38 kernel.  It looks like you tried to upgrade Fedora 38 to 39.  Did the upgrade succeed?  If the upgrade did succeed, have you rebooted into the new kernel?  If you cannot boot into the new kernel, that would indicate issues that would require more information to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how common it is but I had the same issue, seems like something isn't right with the update process from Fedora 38 to 39 but the fix is easy.

Run `uname -r` to check your kernel version, if it's `6.2.9` like for me and the author of this thread you just have to boot into Grub (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot), select the latest available Kernel and boot with that, afterwards `dnf update` should work again!

Comment: Thank you!! This fixed my issue. I nearly reinstalled my hole system :)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem and found the error message a bit misleading. When it says `@System requires kernel-uname-r = 6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64` it sounds like it's looking for another package named "kernel-uname-r" but it isn't.

What it wants is to run `uname -r` and get "6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64" as a response, but the error indicates that it isn't. In my case, this meant "you've kept up with all your updates but you haven't rebooted in 3 years so the running kernel is way out of date."

So when coming across this error, try rebooting the system and run the update command again.